# FindAll() result on Catchable Fatal Error: Object of class DateTime could not be converted to string

Tags: php, datetime, symfony, doctrine-orm

I make a simple findAll function and I get the following error:

> Catchable Fatal Error: Object of class DateTime could not be converted
>   to string in vendor\doctrine\orm\lib\Doctrine\ORM\UnitOfWork.php line
>   2429

```
   $em = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();
   $ppk = $em->getRepository('EgBundle:Table')
                ->findAll();
```

The entities has been created automatically and I didn't made anything specific on this table entity. What is wrong? I don't really understand...

Edit:

So apparently there is a primary key between an integer and a date.

```
if ($class->isIdentifierComposite) {
     (....)
     implode (' ', array('idTrn' => '100', 'date' => object(DateTime)))
```

Comment: are all properties correctly configured?

Comment: Everything has been done automatically from the Symfony app.

Comment: yeah, something can go wrong...

Answer (score 1):

http://www.doctrine-project.org/jira/browse/DDC-1209

> Doctrine 2 has always required id fields to be castable as string,
>   which is not the case of a DateTime object.

It's kind of enoying :s

Edit:

But here there is a recent reported issue

http://www.doctrine-project.org/jira/browse/DDC-2724

Comment: But this issue is more than 1 year ago! It's very strange.